# Netbeans Platform Application: Creating an Idle Lock Screen

Tags: java, netbeans, listener, platform, lockscreen

I'm making an idle lock screen for my NPA. If there are 2 minutes of complete inactivity (no mouse clicks or keys typed) a glass pane comes up with a login prompt.

I read about adding a glass pane to the main window, which is fine and dandy and easily doable, but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to have the *entire* application listen to any and all mouse and keyboard events.

I've tried adding listeners using `WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow().addKeyListener()` but it doesn't seem to work at all.

Has anyone tried this? How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on an old Netbeans forum:

http://forums.netbeans.org/topic18936.html

I would just need to modify the IdleChecker to be able to pause the timer during long processes, but other than that this is exactly what I need.